# How should look configuration for multiple controllers in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have 2 logical items News and Cars. For each of them I need to have separate controllers. How I should configure my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If youre using annotation based configuration, you can simply create 2 Classes that are annotated with @Controller, like:

```
package com.example.controllers;

@Controller
public class NewsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/news")
    public String handleNewsCall() {
        ...
    }

}
```

and

```
package com.example.controllers;

@Controller
public class CarsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cars")
    public String handleCarsCall() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Don't forget to add the following lines to your spring xml if you use annotation based configuration.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```